# SQL Query to compare all the matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to assign Valid Column value to a Variable if the entire result set is valid. so need to write the SQL query that checks the entire result set if the column value is valid(not null and not empty) then assign first column value to that variable else check second column with same condition and assign to variable.

For Example: If my Table has column FirstName with 100 records, I need to check Whether all the records are valid(not null or not empty) records suppose 99th record is empty then I need to check LastName column and assign it to a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName = '' THEN ISNULL(LastName, '')
        ELSE FirstName END 
FROM 
    Tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use If exists to determine if the column is valid:

```
if not exists (select 1 from table where col1 is null)
begin
 select top(1) col1 from table
end
```